# using gdb on fstream of c++

Tags: c++, gdb, fstream

I have a `std::fstream` object in my code, say `std::fstream input` for reading values from files. How can I check the status of input inside the gdb debugger? I tried `print input.fail()`, but it says:

```
couldn't find method std::ifstream::fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you have not installed debug symbols for libstdc++ (this is where `std::fstream` resides).

If you will just try to print `input` variable you will get something like this without debug symbols for libstdc++:

```
(gdb) p input
$1 = <incomplete type>
```

I've reproduced this issue on Fedora and the issue gone (`input` variable was successfully printed and `input.fail()` was called) after I installed debug info with this command:

```
sudo debuginfo-install libstdc++
```

See also the similar issue for `std::stringstream` here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5dwtbb/gdb_looking_into_streams/